# Is there a version of Rotor for .NET 3.5? If so, where?

Tags: .net, rotor

Is there a version of Rotor for .NET 3.5? If so, where?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rotor is the shared source implementation of the runtime itself. The runtime for .NET 3.5 is still CLR 2.0, so the current release should still apply.

Answer (score 2):

Version 1.0 of the Shared Source Common Language Infrastructure can be found at
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=3A1C93FA-7462-47D0-8E56-8DD34C6292F0&displaylang=en.

Version 2.0 can be found at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=8C09FD61-3F26-4555-AE17-3121B4F51D4D&displaylang=en.

Both versions contain an implementation of the Base Class Library in C#.